# Cannot Replicate Shallow Lake Shoreline in 2.8

Tags: texturing

Have vested an unruly number of hours trying to learn Blender. Tried replicating the tutorial on:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgFJ5ER-elg

Seems that Evee was unavailable at the time when this Tut was published. That alone took me 3-days to figure out. We now have the "Principled BSDF" which is throwing off all possible Node translations from previous versions out the window.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Kindest Regards
Nino

Comment: you have the exact same nodes in 2.8, so you should be able to build the exact same node organization. There's a difference with Eevee though as it manages Glass differently, but you need to precise if you plan to use Cycles or Eevee...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it seems rather over-complicated (or over-simplified, depending on how you look at it), the Principled BSDF can be used to make your task rather simple. See the simplicity of the setup below. Note that I changed the Blend Modes to play nice with the alpha. I also took advantage of the Principled BSDF to add a small amount of subsurface color.

[image: PrincipledWater]

If, however, you want to do it the "old fashioned" way, I think you'll find this node arrangement satisfactory. Notice I had to add the normal data in the form of a displacement input in this example.

[image: OldSchoolWater]

EDIT - Here are some images of a working setup done in the file you posted.

EEVEE
[image: EeveeWater]

CYCLES
[image: CyclesWater]

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. This helps making the “transition” into the Principled BSDF.

RE: Moonboot’s reply, guess there’s still a “learning curve“ for me to overcome figuring out Evee’s transparency differences with those in Cycles.

Comment: Evidently I can't even "copy" nodes successfully.

Comment: What do you mean? Is something not working?

Comment: How can I upload/share my Blend File

Comment: Upload here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Copy the URL of this question and paste where it says, then edit your question and paste in the link they give you.

Comment: Done (or so I think). What am I missing? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the link. Maybe try again?

Comment: This it? :   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LSpZVK9g" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LSpZVK9g/)

Comment: Nevermind, look at the shader for you "water" plane. You forgot to connect the Transparent BSDF. To make the water surface look more realistic (show the bump more), increase the scale of the Noise Texture Node to something around 100.

Comment: I added some images to show a working setup to my answer. Have a look, It should clear things up. You can see I also used a MixRGB node to soften the Noise texture (combined it with white) going into the bump node in order to give the waters surface a more "calm" look.